# Permutations list random results

Tags: python, random, permutation

Can someone help with this code, i need it to be able to save a list of permutations and a number after each one, and to print random lets say 20 of them.

for now it works only for the first part..
it prints the permutations of a given word, but i don't know hot to incorporate the second half that is commented, it has to do counts and takes random results.

lets say you want the permutations of "mice", there are 24 rows that should appear, that should be the input for the second half of the code(last 6 rows). using sys.stdin these 24 rows have to be added to counts list.. Every row gets a number (1-24) and then 20 of those are chosen randomly (import math, random must be used) as a result.

input is one word,
output must be 20 random permutations.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks.

```
import sys, re



def gen_permutations(a, n):
 
    if n == 0:
        print(''.join(a))
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            gen_permutations(a, n-1)
            j = 0 if n % 2 == 0 else i
            a[j], a[n] = a[n], a[j]
        gen_permutations(a, n-1)

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.stderr.write('one argument only\n')
    sys.exit(1)


word = sys.argv[1]

gen_permutations(list(word), len(word)-1)

#counts = {}
#for line in sys.stdin:
#     for word in re.findall(r'[a-z\']+', line.lower()):
#         counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
#         for word, count in sorted(counts.items()):
#             print (word, count)
```

Comment: The last 2 lines that report on the contents of `counts` is inside the loop that builds `counts`. Shouldn't your code be waiting until all the input has been processed before reporting on it?

Comment: lets say you want the permutations of "mice", there are 24 rows that should appear, that should be the input for the second half of the code(last 6 rows). using sys.stdin these 24 rows have to be added to counts list.. Every row is given a number (1-24) and then 20 of those are chosen randomly as a result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain it rather than supplementing it in a comment. Sample input and output would also be helpful. *Every list is given a number*: does the user provide that or is the code supposed to do it? Your description is full of passives (*is given, are chosen*). Avoiding those will make it clearer what the requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import permutations
from random import sample

word = ...

perms = sample(list(enumerate(permutations(word))), 20)
for id_val, perm in perms:
    print("".join(perm), id_val)
```

Output for word "abcd":

```
bcad 8
bdca 11
cdba 17
cbad 14
acdb 3
adcb 5
abcd 0
dbac 20
dbca 21
cabd 12
abdc 1
bacd 6
cbda 15
cadb 13
badc 7
bdac 10
cdab 16
dcba 23
dcab 22
dacb 19
```

**Note**: this (as well as your original implementation) generates **all** permutations, even those not used in the output. This means for large words, it will take a much longer time to run than necessary, being O(n!) in nature.

If you find that you run into performance issues, instead you should use `random.choices` to select 20 *indices*, and then generate corresponding those specific permutations corresponding to those indices. You'll find `math.comb` and `math.factorial` useful for this.

---

For counting repeats, you'll want to replace `random.sample` with `random.choices` (to allow repetition), and then use `collections.Counter` to count them.

```py
from itertools import permutations
from random import choices
from collections import Counter

perms = choices(list(enumerate(permutations(word))), k=20)
counts = Counter(counts)

for perm, count in counts.items():
    print("".join(perm), count)
```

Comment: Yes, performance is something that i didn't think of in the beginning.. if you use longer words than 4 chars. Can you give an example with math.comb and math.factorial??   Also i'm not allowed to use itertools.permutations.. i will have to stick to above example for permutations. Otherwise yours it is a very elegant solution.

Comment: @M8Dim see my other answer. The approach was too different + long to merge into this one

Comment: "0" and "19" are repeated.. how this can be avoided?

Comment: @M8Dim replace `random.choices(..., k=20)` with `random.sample(..., 20)`

Comment: I forgot about that in this post-  the other answer does it correctly / doesn't create duplicates

Comment: is it possible to adjust your answer so that permutations are from that gen_permutations above not from  itertools? and this code for counts = {} is used also? otherwise the output is just what i need..

Comment: @M8Dim Regarding `ger_permutations()`, change `print(thing)` to `yield thing` in your code, and it'll be a drop-in replacement for `itertools.permutations`. For the counting, see my edit

Comment: for count i have to use re.findall, and with "yield" what can be the input ? sys.stdin must be replaced i suppose?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer, tackling how to approach this problem from a more mathematical perspective:

```py
from math import factorial
from random import sample


def solve(word, count):
    factorials = [factorial(x) for x in range(len(word))][::-1]
    indices = sample(range(factorial(len(word))), count)
    
    output = []
    for index in indices:
        alphabet = list(word)
        result = ""
        for fact in factorials:
            q, index = divmod(index, fact)
            result += alphabet.pop(q)
        output.append(result)
    return output
```

Example usage

```py
>>> print(solve("abcde", 10))
['bdeca', 'bdcea', 'decba', 'caebd', 'daceb', 'cedba', 'cdbea', 'ebcda', 'decab', 'becad']
```

The way this work is by first selecting indices of permutations to select, and the computes the permutations associated with those indices. A permutation of `n` characters has `n!` permutations, so if our index is larger than that, we are going to need an additional character. We (conceptually) swap out the leading character, subtract the `n!` permutations we skipped over, and see if this new index value is less than `n!` - rinse and repeating until it is. We then repeat on `n-1`, and so on, until we have built the entire permutation, and then do so for the rest of the indices.

The index mapping I use corresponds to the order of `itertools.permutations` as well-  if you have `indices` of `[2, 5, 9]`, the output will be the same as the 2, 5, and 9 'th elements of `list(permutations(...))`.

This implementation is much faster for small sample sizes, since its time complexity is `O(C * S)` - at least if you use small enough numbers that you can treat multiplication as `O(1)`. Otherwise, that factorial pre-computation will be a non-negligible portion of the time complexity.

If you need your results in sorted order, you can sort `indices` before iterating, and the results will be returned in sorted order.